# Shell Script - Running a script assigned to a variable returns "command not found"

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script as follows:

```
var1=some_val1
var2=some_val2
var3=some_val3

varX=another_script.sh ${var1} ${var2} ${var3}
```

I get the following error:

```
./script.sh: line 5: some_val1: command not found
```

How do I get it to run properly? The script basically takes these parameters and runs a Hive query. If I put the Hive query back instead of `another_script.sh blah blah blah`, it works perfectly and the variable captures the value for use later on in the script just fine. I tried swapping it to make it more abstract and I am running into this issue. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: The shell is interpreting your line as being in the form of `a=b command arg1 arg2`, which runs `command` with the environment variable `a` set to value `b`. Thus, you're setting environment variable `varX` to the value `another_script.sh` while running the command named by `var1` (presuming that expands to exactly one word, which isn't guaranteed unless you fix your quoting).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: +1 for explaining why this is happening. Thank you! :)

Comment: ...what I mean by "fix your quoting" is that `another_script.sh "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"` would ensure that the respective contents of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` are each passed as exactly one argument, whereas your current code makes no such guarantee -- each variable expansion could be zero arguments or several (if they contained, say, whitespace or glob characters).

Comment: ...now, it might be even better to track your arguments via a single array rather than a series of almost-identically-named variables, ie. `vars=( some_val1 some_val2 some_val3 ); another_script.sh "${vars[@]}"`, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: (also, using a `.sh` extension is somewhat frowned on -- if you rewrote `another_script` in, say, Python or Ruby, you'd need to either change every caller to use the new extension or have it be named inaccurately -- and by convention, UNIX commands don't have extensions anyhow; you don't run `ls.elf`, after all, you just run `ls`. More haranguing on that topic at http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful).

Comment: So it would work just as well if I removed the .sh?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't put a `.sh` in the command name -- you'd call it as `another_script`, not `another_script.sh`, but yes, it would work just as well. It's the `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` line that tells the operating system to treat it as a shell script (and _which kind_ of shell script to treat it as -- the former is pure POSIX, the latter is bash, and others exist as well); the `.sh` extension has no functional effect at all.

Comment: Wish I could upvote your "fix your quoting" explanation again. It's really good to learn good coding practices. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad to help -- it's a somewhat confusing point. zsh attempts to fix that confusion by breaking the POSIX standard and not word-splitting expansion results even when unquoted, but that's a hazard too, since it leads to folks getting in the habit of not needing to quote (and then potentially writing buggy code out of habit when they're targeting a different shell).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The quoting tip was invaluable. Helped me with another issue I was having. Put the quotes in, and voila! it worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
varX=another_script.sh ${var1} ${var2} ${var3}
```

by

```
varX=$(another_script.sh ${var1} ${var2} ${var3})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and let you know. Thank you :) 

Edit: Worked like a charm! I have other errors now, but at least, not this one! :D